# A sequence in a closed set converges in that set

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am trying to understand the proof of the following theorem.

> Let $X$ be a metric space. If $Z \subset X$ is closed, then for all sequences $\{p_n\}$ in $Z$ which converges to a limit $p \in X$, then $p \in Z$.

This is the proof from my professor's lecture notes.

> Assume there exists $\{p_n\}$ in $Z$ with $p_n \to p$ but $p \in X - Z$. For all open sets $U \owns p$, $U$ contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$, but $p_n \in Z$, so $U \not \subset X - Z$. If $Z$ is closed then $U = X - Z$ is open and we get a contradiction.

There are a few details I don't completely follow, but I'm going to try to flesh out the details as I understand them.

1. The first line is an assumption for the sake of contradiction. We take a convergent sequence of elements in $Z$ which converges to something in the complement in $Z$. The goal is to prove that this leads to nonsense.
2. The second line is a lemma that if $p_n \to p$, every neighborhood of $p$ contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$.
3. So given any open set $U \owns p$, $U$ contains $p$ and infinitely many $p_n$. But $p_n \in Z$, i.e., $p_n \not \in X - Z$, so there exists an element -- infinitely many, in fact -- that are contained in $U$, but not in $X - Z$, so $U \not \subset X - Z$.
4. The $U = X - Z$ line doesn't make sense to me, and I'm not sure whether this is a typo. But if $Z$ is closed, its complement $X - Z$ is certainly open. Since $p \in X - Z$, we should be able to find an open ball $B_{\epsilon} (p) \subset X - Z$. But no such open set containing $p$ is actually contained in $X - Z$, so $p$ is not an interior point of $X - Z$, which is a contradiction.

Have I understood this correctly? Is $U = X - Z$ a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a typo. (3) proves that for *any* open set $U\ni p$, $U$ isn’t contained in $X - Z$. However, we get the contradiction by choosing $U= X-Z$, which is an open set ($Z$ is closed) and it certainly contains $p$. So, by (3), $X-Z\not\subset X-Z$. This is the contradiction.